# How can I create a customized vertical scrolling picker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I want to make (or use a pre-existing) a vertically scrolling list that behaves like UIPickerView with the scrolling and snapping. I simply have a string array @"one", @"two", @"three" etc... that I want to populate the list and the user can scroll and pick whichever they want. I want to be able to customize font color and selected color. I don't know why UIPickerView is so limited in what you can customize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version of UIPickerView:

https://github.com/arkichek/AFPickerView